# Suggestion for Invoice generation in django 1.6

Tags: python, django

I want to generate invoice for my application. I tried by using **reportlab**,however it is not much user friendly. Is there any other modules available to generate the invoice in **django1.6**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to generate a PDF from Django have a look [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/outputting-pdf/). It has an example using reportlab, but also links to 2 other PDF generation libraries and 1 command-line utility to convert HTML to PDF.

Comment: Have a look at this project: https://github.com/radzhome/fedex-commercial-invoice